# Is MarsOne a hoax, or are their claims reasonable?

Tags: technology, space-flight

I was reading a little on [spaceexploration.se](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/4094) and I came across the following comments:

> The amount of nonsense from Mars One is quite astounding. The number of people who have swallowed that nonsense hook, line, and sinker, is even more astounding. –  [David Hammen](https://space.stackexchange.com/users/2752/david-hammen) Apr 26 at 23:17
>
> MarsOne has made extremely improbable claims. They claim that they're going to get by with sending people to mars without recycling water, for example. Which means several tons per person of water that they really don't need to carry, in lieu of several dozen kilograms of equipment and several hundred kilograms of water. There are good reasons to carry that much water, but no good reasons to not carry the recycling gear and a few dozen liters less. –  [aramis](https://space.stackexchange.com/users/158/aramis) May 2 at 9:14

On their site, the MarsOne team claims that:

> While complex, the Mars One Mission is feasible. The science and technology required to place humans on Mars exists today.

and the go into details about the technical aspects of the plan [here](http://www.mars-one.com/mission/technical-feasibility). They further clarify on their [risks and challenges page](http://www.mars-one.com/mission/risks-and-challenges) that they are not developing any new technology, but simply using things that already exist. Therefore, it should be a simple matter to check if we can actually do the things they want to do.

**Is their plan reasonable given the current state of space technology?**

Comment: We can't answer this questions because it's speculative. Surely the folks at [Space.SE] can give a better back-of-the-napkin answer than us.

Comment: If a trip to Mars / you earn / remember, friend / there's no return. [Burma-Shave](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burma-Shave)

Comment: _"On **their** site, the **MarsOne team** claims..."_ not really a valid source, I'd say